# apt-get don't support https and can't install the necessery package to do it

Tags: debian, https, apt

On Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64
I'm using Ansible (software to manage and configure machines) to install Passenger and copy the `sources.list` from another machine. To [install passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html), I need to install `apt-transport-https`, but I keep having the same errror:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: apt-transport-https: Depends: libapt-pkg4.10

I tried to fix and update that package but in vain and I'm currently out of ideas...

Is there another way to make apt-get accept https sources?
apt-transport-https depends on libapt-pkg4.10 but can't work with its upgraded version?

> root@machine:~# apt-cache policy libapt-pkg4.12
>
> libapt-pkg4.12:
>     Installé : 0.9.7.9+deb7u4
>     Candidat : 0.9.7.9+deb7u4
>    Table de version :
>    *** 0.9.7.9+deb7u4 0
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install apt-transport-https from oldstable, that depends on the old libapt-pkg4.10 instead of libapt-pkg4.12. Get the correct version. If all else fails you can find the version from stable (wheezy) [here](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-transport-https)